# Custom filter where you can pass in an enumeration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

Say I have an enumeration like:

```
public enum Permissions
{
   One,
   Two,
   Three
}
```

How can I create a custom filter that I can use on a controller or action that looks like:

```
[PermissionCheck(Permissions.One | Permissions.Two)]
public class MyController : Controller 
{
  ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class PermissionCheckAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public Permissions Permissions {get;set;}

   public PermissionCheck(Permissions permissions)
   {
           Permissions = permissions;
   }
}
```

You can also try using named parameters:

```
[PermissionsCheck(Permissions = Permissions.None)]
```

If the problem you're having is not being able to use multiple enum values then you're not using the `[Flags]` attribute on your enum.  [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)